# Use Session Variable to select a date on one page and have it stay the same date after leaving the page in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-variables

I have a page that allows the user to select a start date. When they select that specific date I would like them to be able to navigate to a different page and then back to that page with the start date remaining the same. Does anyone know how to do this using a session variable in MVC4?

```
  m.StartDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
  m.EndDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

  m.StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 18);
  m.EndDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 18);

  Session["StartDate"] = m.StartDate; 

  if(Session["StartDate"] !=null)
  {
       //show the date selected by the user
  } 
  else {
  m.StartDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 18);
  m.EndDate = new DateTime(2018, 10, 18);
  }

  parameters.StartDate = m.StartDate;
  parameters.EndDate = m.EndDate;
```

View Model:

```
    public List<rptStoreTransferLog> lstFilteredrptStoreTransferLog = new List<rptStoreTransferLog>();
    public List<rptStoreTransferLog> rptStoreTransferLog = new List<rptStoreTransferLog>();
    public List<StoreDefinition> lstStoreDefinition = new List<StoreDefinition>();
    public SelectionFilter SelectionFilter;
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public bool SingleDateSelect;
    public string SearchText = "";
    public string SearchPlaceholderText = "";
    public string PreviousColumnSearch = "StoreName";
    public string strSingleDateSelect = " Single Date Select";
    public int PreviousSelectedDivisionID;
    public int PreviousSelectedProfitCentreID;
    public int PreviousSelectedJobID;
    public int PreviousSelectedStatusID;
    public SelectReportSelections SelectReportSelections = new SelectReportSelections();


View: 

@helper GetSingleDateSelect()
{
  if (Model.SingleDateSelect == true)
  {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SingleDateSelect, new { @checked = "checked" });
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.strSingleDateSelect)
  }
  else
  {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SingleDateSelect);
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.strSingleDateSelect)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only do this if they submit the value to your controller action.

It's unclear from your question exactly how you've wired it up, but you need the date to be an input for the model property, then you'd store that in the session if you wanted to. However normally you'd just send it back in the model for the second page, and keep it there as a hidden value. Then your app remains nice and stateless and you don't have to worry about session variables.

Comment: Hey thanks right now this is my view:                                                          
 '@helper GetSingleDateSelect()
{
  if (Model.SingleDateSelect == true)
  {
    `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SingleDateSelect, new { `@checked = "checked" });
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.strSingleDateSelect)
  }
  else
  {
    `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SingleDateSelect);
    `@Html.DisplayTextFor(m => m.strSingleDateSelect)
  }
}     and this is my model:

Comment: public class StoreTransferLogViewModel
  {
    public List<rptStoreTransferLog> lstFilteredrptStoreTransferLog = new List<rptStoreTransferLog>();
    
    public DateTime StartDate;
    public DateTime EndDate;
    public bool SingleDateSelect; 
    public string PreviousColumnSearch = "StoreName";
    public string strSingleDateSelect = " Single Date Select";
   
    public SelectReportSelections SelectReportSelections = new SelectReportSelections();

Comment: That looks ok, when they navigate to the other page, is it via an anchor link? Because you'd have to submit that model to a controller action for you to be able to save it to a session.

Comment: yes its via an achor link back to home page then links to other pages

Comment: Okay, well the way MVC works is anything that's on the page has to be sent to the server before it knows about it. So once the user selects a date, you have to send it to the server so it knows it exists, by posting your model. So you'd need to either put the element into a `<form>` tag and post it, and then in your Action you can store it in the session, or you could use jquery ajax or similar to send it, but either way it has to go to the server first before you know about it.